# Cannot create NSSet for Object error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am new to CoreData and so I wrote a simple program to learn more about the interaction and how things work - but I keep getting an error. 
I have two Entities, "Parent" and "Child" with a to-many relationship (A Parent can have many children).

Basically, when I add a new child, I need to associate it, add, the Parent. If I pre-populate a ComboBox with the Parent entity, I have no issues, everything works as planned. However, unless I put two combobox's, I can only add ONE parent. Therefore, I need to be able to fetch the Parent, then add. And this is where the error come in.

Code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc}init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[NSEntityDdescription entityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormate:@"firstName like[cd] %@", nameValue];

[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSManagedObject aParent = [results objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"First name: %@", [aParent valueForKey:@"firstName"]);  //This does yield the correct information in NSLog

NSManagedObject *newChild = [.....]; 

[newChild setValue:name forKey:@"firstName"];

//No error to this point, but when I do the next line I receive the error

[newChild setValue:aParent forKey:@"parentName"];
```

I've tried fetching to an NSSet, NSMutableset, etc... I've read just about every Apple CoreData book I can find online and nothing works.

I've been stuck for several days on this one, Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that my code was correct. I forgot one minor/major detail in my CoreData setup, I did not set the relationship to a to-many. I thought I had, however guess I should have double checked.

Anyway, the code I have above worked just fine after I changed the relationship.